SSHFS perms with Qemu/Libvirtd
So, what I'm doing may seem stupid, but.. I have a NAS, of which I'm SSHFSing onto my main user, "User" (1000:1000)'s /home/user/NAS. From there, I'm trying to run Virt-Manager as sudo, and connect a virtual drive on my NAS (inside the SSHFS file system), to it. Virt-manager is able to add the actual device, but once I attempt to run it, I'm getting this error. https://i.sstatic.net/JvdCcI2C.png
The SSHFS command I'm running is sshfs -o uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other,default_permissions user@169.254.119.91:/aeternae NAS
Does anybody have any ideas for alternative ways of doing this? Or better, a way to fix the perms? I've even tried enabling Dynamic Ownership in Libvirt, and still nada.. I've also attempted to run everything (except Qemu) as sudo/root. Furthermore, I've even 777'd the path all the way to the virtual drive, as well as the virtual drive, and still nada. I've gotten this to work on Nix, but I had to run Qemu as Root, which I don't even know how to do here, let alone the security implications it may have.
Oh, and if I use sudo, I can manually open (and mount) the virtual drive, myself. So I don't think it's an SSHFS issue..
Edit: I did just attempt to mount it without sudo, and it permission denied.. Hmm.
